# MySQL stored procedure: variable in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

Can you not do the following w/ MySQL stored procedures?/

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST (team varchar(30))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TEAMS WHERE TEAM_ID = @team;
END
//
```

Where @team (or team) is the variable passed to the stored procedure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST (IN_TEAM_ID varchar(30))
BEGIN

    SELECT t.* 
      FROM TEAMS t
     WHERE t.team_id = IN_TEAM_ID;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

There's no @ notation when referencing stored procedure parameters.

Comment: +1 for pro formatting and expert indentation.  i'd write code with you any day.